# Background is Nil value?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, null

I have a program in which meteors fall toward a character and at line 7 corona simulator throws the error "attempt to index local 'background' (a nil value)" I dont know what is causing this and was hoping someone could help!

Relavent Code:

```
--Start the physics engine!
local physics = require ("physics")

--Get a background image!
local screen_adjustment = 1
local background = display.newImage("Images/Background", true)
background.xScale = (screen_adjustment*background.contentWidth)/background.contentWidth
background.yScale = background.xScale
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is nil because it failed to create it. Double check your filename and path. Are you forgetting the extension for Background.png?

Answer (score 1):

`display.newImage` returns `nil`. Most likely because you don't have a file called `Images/Background`.

Answer (score 1):

The filename given to `display.newImage` is assumed (by default) to reside in your app's resources directory, which is the same folder that contains your `main.lua`. Your code therefore assumes that in the folder that contains `main.lua` you have a folder called `Images` and in there, a file called `Background`. You have to give the extension as well such as `Background.png`.